# How to collect free/bound variables in Lambda Calculus?

Tags: compilers, lambda-calculus, functional-programming

I am building a simple interpreter for untyped lambda calculus, currently trying to implement alpha-reduction.

According to [this document on LC](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~horwitz/CS704-NOTES/1.LAMBDA-CALCULUS.html):

> Alpha-reduction is used to modify expressions of the form "λx.M". It renames all the occurrences of x that are free in M to some other variable z that does not occur in M (and then λx is changed to λz).

It appears that I need to collect the information about the scope (free/bound) of variables prior to alpha-reducing the expression.

How should one go about this? My initial idea was to traverse the AST and produce something similar to a symbol table.

Comment: Usually "alpha conversion" is used because it doesn't really "reduce" anything.

Comment: At any rate, why not try your idea and see what happens?

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track.

Comment: Your strategy looks fine. Sometimes it is convenient to define a capture-avoiding substitution operator first (you'll likely need that anyway), and reuse that for alpha-conversion. Note that, while the set of free variables is stable under alpha-conversion, the set of bound variables is not, so it should be handled with more care. If substitution is made to be capture-avoiding, you might never need to compute bound variables.